# Who Raised Pietro Maximoff in X-Men Evolution?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-evolution

According to the X-Men: Evolution wiki, Pietro was raised by Magneto until he was 13, when Magneto left him in the care of 'a woman who abandoned her own son.'

Who is this woman; Or, who might she be?

Comment: haven't watched XME yet, but if I'm looking at the right wiki, it says: "Not long after this incident, Pietro was also given away to a foster home in New York."

Comment: [x-menevolution.wikia.com](http://x-menevolution.wikia.com/wiki/Quicksilver) says foster home.

Answer (score 3):

While I can't vouch for the veracity of the wiki,  my initial thought of women who Magneto knows,  and who abandoned their own son leads me to think this was Mystique,  who abandoned her son Kurt Wagner.

Comment: That was mu first thought, but Mystique didn't meet him until he was older.

Comment: @axxieD or so she says. Is need to re-watch all those episodes to be certain.

Comment: She says, "so this is the young speed demon I've heard so muc about." If not for that, I'd definitely say Mystique. (I do like the mental image of Magneto bragging about Pietro, though. ) But I guess it's still a possibility,  if she managed to keep it from Magneto.

Comment: @axxieD it's possible she didn't know him by his code name, or she has raised him in disguise.

Comment: I could definitely believe that second one. She obviously knew about him and Wanda. Though, she didn't exactly abandon Kurt in XME. But that's beside the point.